# Fullcalendar Week Title Format

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Is it possible to get fullcalendar to show week titles as a single letter? So instead of the default:

> Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat

how can I display:

> S  M  T  W  T  F  S

I've tried:

> ```
> $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
>    header: {
>    right: '',
>    center: 'prev, title, next',
>    left: ''
>   },
>   columnFormat: {
>     month: 'd' //also tried 'D' but a number displayed instead
>   }
> )}
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortest you can get is two letters

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   header: {
   right: '',
   center: 'prev, title, next',
   left: ''
  },
  columnFormat: {
    month: 'dd' //also tried 'D' but a number displayed instead
  }
});
```

This library uses moment library and all possible formats can be found [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Comment: Thanks, will go with two letters for now instead of some hack to get it down to one.

Answer (score 1):

From version 2.2.4,

You have to modify like this.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
    ...
    ...,
    views: {
        week: { // name of view
            columnFormat: 'dd'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using dayGridMonth, inside the option apply ,

```
dayHeaderFormat: {
    weekday: 'narrow'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use slotLabelFormat:

```
slotLabelFormat: [
    { weekday: 'narrow' },
]
```

All possible formats are in documentation:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/date-formatting